# Unable to get this NPM command to run on Mojave

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, google-chrome, npm, macos-mojave

Want to use this [chrome-aws-lambda](https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda) project. Cannot get this command to run on OSX Mojave:

Is there a specific directory I should be in to run this command?

Is there a specific way I need to modify the command to be compatible with Mojave?

```
MacBook-Pro:chrome-aws-lambda juan$ npm pack && \
> mkdir --parents nodejs/node_modules/chrome-aws-lambda/ && \
> tar --directory nodejs/node_modules/chrome-aws-lambda/ --extract -- 
file chrome-aws-lambda-*.tgz --strip-components=1 && \
> rm chrome-aws-lambda-*.tgz && \
> zip -9 --filesync --move --recurse-paths _/chrome-aws-lambda.layer.zip nodejs/
npm notice 
npm notice   chrome-aws-lambda@1.0.0
npm notice === Tarball Contents === 
npm notice 213B package.json
npm notice === Tarball Details === 
npm notice name:          chrome-aws-lambda                       
npm notice version:       1.0.0                                   
npm notice filename:      chrome-aws-lambda-1.0.0.tgz             
npm notice package size:  250 B                                   
npm notice unpacked size: 213 B                                   
npm notice shasum:        f719b0ff945036a499583e6053d2e80345cc4a0a
npm notice integrity:     sha512-JDqf17BONl8f/[...]YbnkKo25JUCNA==
npm notice total files:   1                                       
npm notice 
chrome-aws-lambda-1.0.0.tgz
mkdir: illegal option -- -
usage: mkdir [-pv] [-m mode] directory ...
MacBook-Pro:chrome-aws-lambda juan$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macs don't understand long form parameters (like `--parents` in your case). Replace long form params by short forms:

```
mkdir --parents -> mkdir -p
tar --directory -> tar -C
    --extract -> -x
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question, updated command is    `npm pack && mkdir -p nodejs/node_modules/chrome-aws-lambda/ && tar -C nodejs/node_modules/chrome-aws-lambda/ -xf chrome-aws-lambda-*.tgz && rm chrome-aws-lambda-*.tgz && zip -9 -filesync -move -recurse-paths _/chrome-aws-lambda.layer.zip nodejs/`